# How can I append a dictionary in a JSON file, whilst maintaining correct JSON format

Tags: python, json

Before I talk you through my problem I am sure this is not a duplicate question, my issue is quite unique.

So I want to append to a dictionary within a JSON file using the following code, please note items such as `k['Process']` are pulled from a separate JSON file, I didn't include that section of my code as it works fine and is not relevant to my problem.

```
 import json
 data = {}
 data['numdata'] = []
 with open(r'E:\data\loc.json', 'a') as outfile:
    if (k['Process']) == 'New' and (k['Test']) == 0:
        Num1 = k['Num']
        Time = k['Time']

        data['numdata'].append({
        'Num': Num1,
        'Time': Time
        })


        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=False, ensure_ascii=False)
```

The aim is to run this every five minutes and have it append the JSON file with the data dictionary, hence the append mode when opening the file. The issue comes in when the data is dumped. It looks like this:

```
{
    "numdata": [
        {
            "Num": "000540",
            "Time": "2018-06-14 10:37:13"
        }
    ]
}{
    "numdata": [
        {
            "Num": "002077",
            "Time": "2019-03-08 13:12:35"
        }
    ]
}
```

Naturally this is not correct JSON format, I would like it to look like this so that every time I append the JSON it adds to `numdata` dict... only I cannot figure out what needs to be changed in my current code:

```
   {
        "numdata": [
            {
                "Num": "000540",
                "Time": "2018-06-14 10:37:13"
            },
            {
                "Num": "002077",
                "Time": "2019-03-08 13:12:35"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: Where is `data` defined?

Comment: @GPhilo ah my bad, I removed it by mistake when simplifying my question. I will add it in now

Comment: How big is your resulting file? can you not just keep it open as a dictionnary and update the keys you need then dump the updated dictionnary into JSON?

Comment: @DaveMaheux fairly large, 200,000+ lines only included a small sample here

Comment: Your data dictionnary and numdata list are empty when you upload your entries in them... you are appending to nothing, you will definitely need to load what's in there in your numdata list and then only append to it.

Comment: @DaveMaheux of course! I've got it now thanks, if you put this as an answer I will mark correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data dictionnary and numdata list are empty when you upload your entries in them... you are appending to nothing, you will definitely need to load what's in there in your numdata list and then only append to it.

EDIT: Just to clarify as for someone else looking for an answer, i've vulgarised in my own words that his data dictionnary and numdata list were out of scope.

In the original code, the user creates a new empty dictionnary and list, then appends to it, and dumps it back in his json.

The data needs to be taken somewhere, then appended to it. here is a small example :

```
data = {'list':['apple', 'banana', 'orange']}

def update_data(newitem):
    data = {}
    data['list'] = []
    data['list'].append(newitem)
    print(data)
```

The update_data function above will show the empty dictionnary like this:

```
{'list':[<newitem>]}
```

The result we were after was more like:

```
{'list':['apple', 'banana', 'orange', <newitem>]}
```

The fix would be to load the data first have it be in the same scope, then append to it.

```
def update_data(newitem):
    global data
    data['list'].append(newitem)
    print(data)
```